# How can i get parent page name in the user control page using C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i have about 10 pages using the same User Control,now i need to know each time what Page invoked the user control.and i need the page name(title).

Answer (score 7):

Try using within the control code:

```
this.Page.Title
```

Comment: Already tried,its just returns empty string,by the way my page that call the User Control is a part of a Master Page.

Comment: What about `this.Page.Header.Title` or `this.Page.Page.Title`? And make sure that page actually has a Title

Answer (score 2):

This is using javascript ,

```
<script language="javascript">
var parentName= "<%= System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Page.Request.Path) %>";    
</script>
```

or

```
this.Parent.Page.Title;
```